# How do I disprove a set is not a subset of another set?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Given that $T=\{3t|t \in\mathbb Z\}$, $Q=\{5q|q \in\mathbb Z\}$, $R=\{6r|r \in\mathbb Z\}$ and $S=\{T,Q,R\}$.
How can I disprove that Q $\subseteq$  R?

I tried the following:

Let $q=2, Q={10}$
Let $r=2,  R={12}$,

Therefore Q is not a subset of R.

Is that the right way to disprove the statement?
Thank you.

Comment: Note that $Q\ne\{10\}$. Rather $Q=\{\ldots,-15,-10,-5,0,5,10,\ldots\}$

Comment: Let's suppose for a brief moment that $Q=\{10\}$ and $R=\{12\}$ (which they are **not**). How exactly would that make Q a subset of R?

Comment: sorry, I missed the not a subset part when I was typing.

Comment: Oh, you meant $\not\subseteq$. Well, then you are on the right track, except Q is not just {10}.

Comment: So I should list out the possible elements for Q and R in this case?

Comment: Well, with both sets being infinite, this may take quite a while, but if we use the omission dots...

Answer (score 0):

$q=2$, $10\in Q$ (not $Q={‎\lbrace ‎10\rbrace‎}$. ) and $10\notin R$